# Different between Systick and Timer in ARM M4

Tags: timer, arm, cortex-m

I completed a basic microprocessor with 8051. In this course I learned using a timer to trigger an event. After a semester, I learned programming Embedded System with ARM Cortex M4 (Tiva C launchpad) and started to use Systick to trigger event ( almost used in FreeeRTOS) and sometimes it is used as a timer.

- I wonder what different between timer and systick? Because sometime I
  think systick behavior is the same as timer. I have searched the
  differ, and know: systick is in arm core and timer is of chip vendor.
- And which situation we should use systick intead of using timer?
  Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is any OS developer can write code for *any* Cortex-M which has SysTick, and not need to worry about the vendor specific details. There is a guarantee that SysTick always works the same way across a wide range of devices so there is less low-level porting to be done.

Same for your course, if you are writing bare metal, you don't need to worry about the device vendor until you use their peripherals (timer, uart, watchdog).

Answer (score 6):

You basically have it.  The systick timer is part of the ARM core.  And the other timer(s) are from the chip vendor.  You, the programmer are free to use them however you wish.

They most likely have different features, the systick timer is pretty much only for polling or interrupts of simple durations.  Where the chip vendor timers can do those things usually and much more, sometimes they can generate clocks for other timers sometimes they can generate clocks or signals that go out a pin, sometimes they can time inputs.  Sometimes a vendor will have multiple timers in a chip and those timers have features different from each other.  It varies widely.

Note some ARM cores do not have a systick timer or lets say the chip vendor has the option to compile the core without it.  In those situations your only choice is the chip vendor supplied timers.

There is no magic here you are the programmer you are free to use the peripherals as you wish.

Now if you use an RTOS like FreeRTOS or others, then your freedom is limited to what the RTOS does not consume for itself (it will likely consume the systick timer if present, but leave others).